# Symfony autoloader component doesn't load my classes

Tags: php, class, symfony, autoload, psr-0

I'm trying to setup symfony class loader component for one of my projects. When I try to create a new object from the Logger class I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyPrefix\Log\Logger' not found in /usr/htdocs/sf/index.php on line 12
```

Here is the structure of the project

```
/
 lib
    MyPrefix
      Log
        Logger.php
 vendor/
 index.php
```

Here is the content of index.php file

```
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassLoader;

$loader = new ClassLoader();
$loader->addPrefix('MyPrefix', __DIR__ .'/lib/MyPrefix/');
$loader->register();


use MyPrefix\Log\Logger;
$logger = new Logger();
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `use MyPrefix\Logger\Logger`?

Comment: @Lauri Elias the directory name was wrong. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add new prefix for namespace, you should give parent directory.

So for `MyPrefix` it is `__DIR__ . '/lib/'`